# Any element $x \in D_{2n}$, represented as $rx=xr^{-1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am working through  problems in Dummit and Foote and am having a hard time interpreting this question.

Use the generators and relations to shat if if $x$ is any element in $D_{2n}$, which is not of power $r$, then $rx=xr^{-1}$

I thought this relation was already given in presentation of $D_{2n}$. How do I interpret this problem?

$D_{2n}= < r,s | r^n=s^2=1, \hspace{2mm} \underline{rs=sr^{-1} } >$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = sr^k$. Then $rx = rsr^k = sr^{-1}r^k = sr^{k-1} = sr^kr^{-1} = xr^{-1}$ since powers of $r$ commute. I believe this is all they are looking for.